# Report builder group not retrieving correct data

Tags: reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I have a parameter at the top where someone can choose 1 or more divisions.

[image]

A group is used to repeat a table for the divisions. In my db I have asigned values stat1, stat2 and stat3 for automotive and stat4, stat5 and stat6 for equipment. For some reason it is reapeating automotives data and not retrieving equipments data, but it retrieves the correct division.

It's doing this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

The second one, is supposed to be stat4, stat5 and stat6. Not what it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I un-ticked `allow multiple values` and just went with single selection parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment yet so I'm going to try answer:

Try deleting any .data files and then re-running. I have noticed that sometimes in debug mode it re-uses the previous data.

Check that the parameters are set up correctly:
The parameter expression to pass it to a query should be:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,","),",")
```

In your query you should be using:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Division] IN (@Parameter)
```

Comment: +1 for attempting to answer the question with a valid answer, but I went with single selection parameters.